Repairing drywall behind water heater: worth doing now, or wait until heater end of life?
I recently purchased a condo. The seller informed us that a while back (1-2 years ago) the electric water heater had leaked while he was on vacation. The sheetrock behind the heater was damaged. During inspection, the inspector looked at the damage and noted it in the report as "minor damage to wall behind water heater". The damage: https://imgur.com/a/6qyLDQc
The water heater is 6 years old. I do not believe it has been flushed/maintained regularly.
My question: is it acceptable to wait until the water heater is at its end of life (in 4-6 years), and repair the sheetrock then, between removal and new unit installation? OR is it important to do this now, and if so what kind of risk would there be to the heater in moving it given the age and maintenance history?

If you start doing maintenance now, you might get another twenty years out of it.  Would be nice to know how/what leaked exactly.  Piping/valves is good.   About the only damage you can do to them is dropping them down, when moving.

There appears to be some mold growth there. That may panic some people. Therefore this question will foster opinions and most likely be closed.
I believe I would attempt to kill the mold with a surface spray suited for the purpose.  If that is successful and there is no further concern or debate from my better half, I would leave it until the water heater needs replaced.
Again that is my opinion.  I stand by that since the report also stated the damage was "minor"  and no immediate repairs were warranted.  I'm sure you will get other opinions.  So the bottom line here is, You will need to make the final decision yourself.

Yeah, at this point I'd just try to remediate the mold and leave the wallboard, unless it was causing a draft or something.  Leave the wall repair until you have better access when the water heater is replaced.
